# comparison theorem in ode

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Prove ode solution has boundary:

Hello, suppose the ode equation as follows
$$ \ddot{y} + R(t)y(t) = 0$$
where $R(t)> 0$ bounded, $t\in (t_0,t_2)$.

For discuss convenient, we add some addition condition in $R$, if $t\in (t_0,t_1)$, $\dot{R}\leq 0$, and $t\in (t_1,t_2)$, $\dot{R}\geq 0$.

I can proof in the left interval, $y(t)$ is bounded. here is my attempt:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(R y^2 + \dot{y}^2) = 2\dot{y}(\ddot{y}+R y^2) + \dot{R} y^2 \leq 0 $$

then $$ R y^2 \leq \dot{y}^2 + R y^2 \leq \dot{y}(t_0)^2 + R y(t_0)^2 = M_0$$

so $$y\leq \sqrt{\frac{M_0}{R}}$$

how to get the right interval result,  get the  upper boundary of $y$?

Is there a more general result for $R\geq 0 $? ie.  $y$ has upper and lower bounds .

Comment: For a linear DE, its solutions exist and are bounded over each closed interval where the coefficients are continuous (and the leading coefficient is not zero). Your equation is a special case of that.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That doesn't seem to be the case. This is a [counterexample](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/dgaranin/Mechanics/Parametric_resonance.pdf).

Comment: It is somewhat of a demerit that the name "Matthieu equation" is not mentioned in the script. I meant over closed and finite intervals, as is used in the task above. // The comparison theorem is more concerned with angles and phase differences, was there really a demand for a quantitative bound and does it simplify the ensuing steps?